# EF Core get entities that are higher than one column, but lower than one other entities

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

If I would have an entity `Bucket` with two values.

```
public class Bucket
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  
  public int MinimumNumberOfApples { get; set; }
}
```

```
ID | MinimumNumberOfApples
--------------------------
1 | 0 
2 | 0
3 | 2
4 | 2
5 | 5
6 | 5
```

So if I would want to get a `List<Bucket>` from EF Core where `MinimumNumberOfApples` would be higher then the entity but lower then other enities.

Requirements:

- Should return `List<Bucket>` that are the same size
- Should select buckets that are closest related to the number below. So `4` is closest related to `2` below, not to `5` because it is higher.

For example I have `3` apples and I want a `List<Bucket>` which are **most suitable**. That means where `MinimumNumberOfApples >= 2` but `MinimumNumberOfApples < 5` in this case. Because `Bucket` with ID `3, 4` are good, but ID `5, 6` are too big. I ONLY want to return buckets with the same size. So in the list we could never have buckets with minimum size of 2 and 5 combined.

How do I write this query in EF Core?

```
private readonly DbContext _context; // set in constructor

public async Task<IEnumerable<Bucket>> GetMostSuitableBuckets(int numOfApples)
{
  var buckets = await _context
     .Buckets // is a DbSet<Bucket>
     .Where(i => i) // What now?
     .ToListAsync();

  // do something with these buckets

  return buckets;
}
```

Comment: What are your rules for excluding buckets with id 1 and 2 that have minimum number of apples of 0?

Comment: @G_P because `2` is higher the `0` is not "best suited". See it as something vertical, when you jump you would land on 2 because this is higher then 0. Also you wouldn't land on 5 because this is above your max height (4).

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the screen for 10 minutes I found a solution to my problems. I need to do it in two steps.

```
var buckets = await _context
  .Buckets
  .OrderBy(i => i.MinimumNumberOfProfiles)
  .Where(i => numOfApples >= i.MinimumNumberOfApples )
  .ToListAsync();

return buckets 
  .GroupBy(i => i.MinimumNumberOfApples )
  .OrderBy(i => i.Key)
  .FirstOrDefault()?
  .ToList();
```

Note that this isn't perfect because if would filter out some items on the SQL side but I am still doing some client side filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - I'm not sure I'm exactly following your requirements pertaining to the "closest related", but I'll give it a go:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Bucket>> GetMostSuitableBuckets(int numOfApples)
{
  var buckets = await _context
     .Buckets // is a DbSet<Bucket>
     .Where(i => 
            i.MinimumNumberOfApples < numOfApples && 
            i.MinimumNumberOfApples == _context.Buckets
                  .Where(j => j.MinimumNumberOfApples <= numOfApples)
                  .Max(j => j.MinimumNumberOfApples))
     .ToListAsync();

  // do something with these buckets

  return buckets;
}
```

I haven't been able to test this, and I just saw your answer pop up- but I'll post this in case it helps.